# GWT: RPC and MVP and Place Tokenizer

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-mvp

I'm just starting off on my first attempt at the [MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) architecture in [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/).

My understanding is that the job of `PlaceTokenizer.getPlace(String)` is to take the token in the URL after the hash, parse it, and return a `Place` with the object to which that token refers.

In my application, I have a resource (say, a video), which I tokenize by the video's unique id. Then my `getPlace` method ought to take this id, and retrieve the video information from the server. Is this the right approach?

As far as how to execute this, the only way that I could figure out would be to have my `RemoteService` right on the `PlaceTokenizer`, and make the call right in that `getPlace` method. Something about this made me hesitate. It seems like the call would be better suited for the `Activity` or somewhere else.

Is this how it's done? If not, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Place` doesn't need to download the video.  It could just contain the video's id.

Your `Activity` will receive the `Place`, which has the video id, and now the `Activity` can do the downloading or whatever heavy lifting you want.

So: Your `PlaceTokenizer` only needs to know enough to store the video id in the `Place`. Let the `Activity` do the work after that.  The only function of `getPlace` is to turn a String into a `Place`.

It helped me to mentally rename `Place` to `PlaceTag`. The place objects really do not represent places - they represent tags or pointers to places.  The actual *place* is represented by, terribly, the `Activity`.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot more sense. So instead of the `getPlace` transforming the id to a `Resource` (video container), and the `Place` holding the `Resource`, instead the `getPlace` can generate a place and the `Place` can just hold the id. Then do I make the RPC call in the `Activity` constructor, or in the `start` method?

Comment: I use the constructor to inject dependencies like my RPC-making class, app-wide state information, etc.  Then the `start` method does the actual calling.  Well... actually my `start` method just gets an instance of the appropriate display and an instance of the appropriate presenter and hooks them up, and then the _presenter_ does the RPC calling... but that may be more abstraction than you need.

Comment: Awesome, this is starting to make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

if i may help clarifying the place signification a little more. Your place object is a serializable representation of the **state** of your client. it will help the activity restoring the screen to its former state by containing all the information you need to build it back.